# pyttsx3 delays print statement on the previous line

Tags: python, printing, output, newline, pyttsx3

I've noticed a weird bug when using `pyttsx3.speak()` after a print statement that has the `end=''` argument set. Take a look at my code.

I've done a bit of research, and I couldn't find anything that's related to this issue. And I couldn't find a reason why exactly this is happening. The first thing that came to my mind is that maybe the default `print()` function behavior won't print the statement, unless there's a new line. Like the standard output isn't printed to unless there's a new line.

```py
import pyttsx3

print("This should be before speaking, ", end='')
pyttsx3.speak("Hi")
print("and this should be after speaking")
```

The normal logic would be that it would print the first statement, speak `hi`, then print the second statement. However, it doesn't print anything until `pyttsx3.speak()` finishes. This only happens if I specify `end=''` in the print statement. If I remove it, the logic is completely fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. It might help you to [*flush* your output.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) by adding the keyword argument `flush=True` to your `print` function call.

Comment: Yes, I've included that in my answer if you look down below.

Comment: Also, could you please tell me why my code isn't "minimal reproducible example"?

Comment: I didn't think your example code was sufficient because it didn't work for me and it doesn't match the [example code](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#speaking-text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue isn't with pyttsx3, but it's a feature in `print()`

Ok, so it appears that the same issue happens even with using `time.sleep()` function, which means that `pyttsx3` isn't the issue. I looked in the documentation of `print()` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#print), and specified `flush=True` with the first statement, and it worked completely fine.

From my understanding, when you don't have a newline in your print statement, the output would still be in the buffer till there's a new line. So technically, the print statement is executed, but the output is still in the buffer and not visible to you. When you do `flush=True`, you force the output to go the stdout instead of staying in the buffer. I don't know why this isn't mentioned particularly in Python documentation.

Thanks for reading this. Would it be normal to create an issue on Github on the official Python repository for that? To recommend adding this detail to the documentation.

### Edit

This feature is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/sys.html#sys.stdout). It says that `Changed in version 3.9: Non-interactive stderr is now line-buffered instead of fully buffered`, which makes sense now.